# C# memory/object understanding

Tags: c#

If I instantiate an object like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static PlayerShip mainShip = new PlayerShip(); 
}
```

And then in another class I do:

```
public class RandomEncounters
{
    var subShip = new PlayerShip();

    public void PlayEncounter()
    {
        subShip = Program.mainShip;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that both `subShip` and `mainShip` are now referencing the same object in the 'heap' or memory. Is this correct, and also, is this a bad idea?

Comment: Why the `PlayerShip subShip = new PlayerShip();` line instead of `PlayerShip subShip;` you are creating two instances but you are overwriting the reference to this instance with a reference to the PlayerShip of the Program class

Comment: Good point! I changed it. You are right it makes no sense to do new playership if im just overwriting the reference. Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry about heap or stack. Worry about copy-by-reference or copy-by-value; that is the relevant difference that you need to understand.

Comment: I agree with Lanorkin, it's not a bad or good idea. There are times where you would want that behavior, and there are times you don't. If you do, you can use a class, if not, you can use a struct.

Answer (score 8):

> My understanding is that both subShip and mainShip are now referencing the same object in the 'heap' or memory.

If `PlayerShip` is a `class` then yes, you will have two references for the same object.

If `PlayerShip` is a `struct` then no, assignment will a create a copy and will use that copy.

> is this a bad idea

That's neither bad nor good, that's just a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just assume that Playership is a class. Then you have different states of your execution:

```
public class RandomEncounters
{
    PlayerShip subShip = new PlayerShip();    //a
```

Now you have to different references. One reference is from the static object `mainShip` and the other is from the just instantiated object `subShip`. But after you call the method:

```
    public void PlayEncounter()
    {
        subShip = Program.mainShip;
    }
}
```

You reference to the static object `mainShip`, so both `subShip` and `mainShip` are referencing the same object.

> is this a bad idea?

What exactly? To reference to another object? No, it's not a bad idea and it's used quite often.

But it is not a good idea to assign your object directly (I marked the line with an a) if you never use the firstly assigned object (I can't see any use, maybe you used `subShip` already before executing `PlayEncounter()`, then it would make sense again). But if you didn't use it you directly overwrite the old reference, it was just a waste of RAM space and execution time. It's not a big difference, but you can't call it a good idea either.